# Process a string using foldr where '#' means deleting the previous character

Tags: list, haskell, fold

I need to process a string using `foldr` where `'#'` means deleting the previous character. For example:

```
>backspace "abc#d##c"
"ac"

>backspace "#####"
""
```

It needs to be done using `foldr` through one pass of the list, without using `reverse` and/or `(++)`.

Here what I have got so far:

```
backspace :: String -> String
backspace xs = foldr func [] xs where
  func c cs | c /= '#' = c:cs
            | otherwise = cs
```

But it just filter the `'#'` from the string. I thought about deleting the last element of current answer every time `c == '#'` and got something like that

```
backspace :: String -> String
backspace xs = foldr func [] xs where
  func c cs | c /= '#' = c:cs
            | cs /= [] = init cs
            | otherwise = cs
```

but it is not working properly,

```
ghci> backspace "abc#d##c" 
"abc"
```

Comment: Likely you don't need `reverse` because `foldr` operates in reverse, from the right. Were you told that `foldr` should return the actual string directly ? Or may `foldr` return some final *state* from which you can easily extract the actual string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `(Int, String)` as state for your `foldr` where the first `Int` is the number of backspaces, and the `String` is the current string constructed.

This thus means that you can work with:

```
backspace :: String -> String
backspace = snd . foldr func (0, [])
  where func '#' (n, cs) = (n+1, cs)
        func c (n, cs)
                 | n > 0 = …      -- (1)
                 | otherwise = …  -- (2)
```

In case we have a character that is not a `#`, but `n > 0` it means we need to remove that character, and thus ignore `c` and decrement `n`. In case `n == 0` we can add `c` to the `String`.

I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise.